# Emulate SD Card as internal hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, sd-card

I'm currently using my SD card (32Gb) as a secondary memory storage because my Windows 8 (not RT) tablet has too little space (50+Gb) by default. I expect to leave the SD card plugged in all the time.

I'd like to be able to install some applications onto my SD Card, but often applications only allow installing onto internal hdds, so I'm wondering if there's a way to let my computer see my SD card as a hard disk as well?

Comment: Format it to use NTFS filesystem. You'll probably have to either use a tool of some sort or do it using command line (`diskpart.exe`)

Comment: As far as cons are concerned at least SD card will at least be slower than HDD, I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the SD Card to a folder on the disk by mapping it (map network drive but locally).

Comment: Your answer isn't very clear.  How would mapping it as a network drive make Windows think it's a local HDD?   Can you provide steps to map the drive as you are suggesting?

Comment: Standard Windows mapping drive to drive. There is possibility, that it would be treated as a non-removable media (for apps installation). There are two options: map local HDD folder to SD card (subst) or map drive to SD card. It depends on what type of tablet it is and what kind of operating system it uses.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got it to work! The guide I used was http://www.rbrussell.com/2012/12/04/tech-tip-how-to-mount-sd-cards-as-a-local-drive-in-windows/ Basically create a empty folder and use Disk Management to map SD card to the folder. I was able to install Photoshop on my sd card, and the best part? I can remove and insert the card as per normal, without needing to reconfigure the mapping!

Comment: Great! Happy that I've helped.

Comment: The best solution I've found: https://garvis.ca/2013/02/21/converting-an-sd-card-to-permanent-storage-in-windows-devices/