# Is it possible to backup data on a piece of external media (SD card) and nothing else to my HD?

Tags: windows-7, backup, sd-card

This is about Windows 7 (Ultimate, x64).

Inserting a SD into its slot and right-clicking on its icon has "Properties" last in the menu.

When I choose it, the last entry on the second tab ("Tools") is Backup. When I click on `Back up now...`, another window opens (Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Backup and Restore), whereupon it is written that Windows Backup has not been set up and there is an admin-labeled option `Set up backup`.

When I click on it, I am offered a choice of the backup destination - disk D:, DVD drive and the SD itself, as well as saving on a network.

Saving on network means LAN afaik, so I choose D:.

When I choose D:, I get a warning that it is on the same physical disk as my system drive, but I am still allowed to continue.

When I click on `Next`, I have a choice between letting Windows choose what to back up and choosing myself.

When I choose the latter, the listing of what I can back up does not include the SD.

I don't want to back up anything except data on SD, how can I do it?

(I am aware of various tools that I may install, I just want to know whether it may be done with Windows backup system itself)

Comment: Map the SD card as [internal folder](http://superuser.com/questions/637066/emulate-sd-card-as-internal-hard-disk), add it as a library (probably not required) and Windows backup should recognize it.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo Many thanks for sharing the idea! Unfortunately this did not work. Without adding it as a library it is still not among the items I can choose for backup. I created a library, but when I tried to add the mapped drive to it, Windows refused because it is not indexed. Help says in this case I must make it always available offline. I did it and tried again, but the result was the same.